# updates-testing repo for CentOS 6?

Tags: centos, redhat, centos6, rhel6

What is the equivalent CentOS 6 repo for the **updates-testing** repo of RHEL/Fedora? I am trying to follow the node.js installation instructions [here](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Installing-Node.js-via-package-manager) and am having trouble figuring out what repo to add for CentOS 6.

```
Error getting repository data for updates-testing, repository not found
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you install Node.JS on CentOS?](http://serverfault.com/questions/299288/how-do-you-install-node-js-on-centos)

Comment: You don't. Those instructions are for Fedora only.

Comment: @MichaelHampton node.js was just one example of a package that might be found there. I would not consider this question a duplicate of the other (yes I read that one first)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Available Repositories for CentOS](http://wiki.centos.org/AdditionalResources/Repositories)

Read under 'Additional CentOS Provided Repositories'.  I believe the repository you are looking for is `CentOS-Testing`.  You'll have to install it manually, as it doesn't come installed by default.  The CentOS-Testing repo can be found at:

http://dev.centos.org/centos/6/testing/CentOS-Testing.repo

Comment: Thanks. It looks like this is the equivalent (in purpose) repo for CentOS. It doesn't happen to have the package I am looking for (nodejs) but I believe the answer is correct based on what I asked.

Comment: There's a serverfault question [How do you install Node.JS on CentOS?](http://serverfault.com/questions/299288/how-do-you-install-node-js-on-centos) that points to an RPM repo, but I think RHEL hasn't brought node.js into testing yet.