# How to install latest nodejs package on Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6?

Tags: node.js, rhel6

Would this sequence of commands work for RHEL?

```
apt-get install python g++ make
mkdir ~/nodejs && cd $_
wget -N http://nodejs.org/dist/node-latest.tar.gz
tar xzvf node-latest.tar.gz && cd `ls -rd node-v*`
./configure
make install
```

I should install it in the future, but I have no access to RHEL machine right now...

Comment: node.js publishes binaries too in the same site as you linked in your script. See my answer [here](http://serverfault.com/questions/299288/how-do-you-install-node-js-on-centos/480051#480051) on one way to use them. Lots of other good information in other answers of that question which should apply to RHEL too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

RHEL is RPM based Linux and apt-get is used for Deb based Linux .Yum is the Package Updater for RPM based Linux.

However you can download the latest NOdeJS package and compile it on your RHEl6

```
  http://nodejs.org/download/

  tar -zxf node-v0.6.18.tar.gz #Download this from nodejs.org
  cd node-v0.6.18
  ./configure && make && sudo make install
```

Or, if you'd like to install from the repository

```
  git clone https://github.com/joyent/node.git
  cd node
  git checkout v0.6.18 #Try checking nodejs.org for what the stable version is
  ./configure && make && sudo make install
```

Comment: I tried now with  'node-v4.1.1-linux-x64' and get error .."./configure: No such file or directory".