# CentOS installing node.js no configure

Tags: installation, node.js, centos6.5

I'm trying to install a defined version `node-v0.10.16-linux-x64` on CentOS 6.5. And following dependencies:

```
Python 2.6.6 (r266:84292, Jan 22 2014, 09:42:36)
gcc (GCC) 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-4)
```

But when I've tried to `./configure` I realized there is no file:

```
# ls -lsa node-v0.10.16-linux-x64
total 192
  4 drwxr-xr-x. 5 root root   4096 Aug 16  2013 .
  4 drwxr-xr-x. 3 root root   4096 Oct 28 09:29 ..
  4 drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root   4096 Aug 16  2013 bin
124 -rw-r--r--. 1 root root 124984 Aug 16  2013 ChangeLog
  4 drwxr-xr-x. 4 root root   4096 Aug 16  2013 lib
 44 -rw-r--r--. 1 root root  41356 Aug 16  2013 LICENSE
  4 -rw-r--r--. 1 root root   1635 Aug 16  2013 README.md
  4 drwxr-xr-x. 3 root root   4096 Aug 16  2013 share
```

So how can i install this specific version?

// I've ridden [How do you install Node.JS on CentOS?](https://serverfault.com/questions/299288/how-do-you-install-node-js-on-centos), but it wasn't helpfull in my case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have downloaded the wrong file.
You need the full source to be able to do this.

Please look at this one:

```
cd /tmp
wget http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.10.16/node-v0.10.16.tar.gz
tar -xvzf node-v0.10.16.tar.gz
ls -l node-v0.10.16/
```