# Correct Way to Install Node.js in a Multiuser Server?

Tags: linux, web-hosting, node.js, javascript

I have to acknowledge being an old timer U*ix system administrator. Software to be used by everybody had two possible locations:

/usr/bin
/usr/local/bin

The best example is gcc and family.

Now I find myself in a new world. My node installation lives in:

/home/david/.nvm/versions/node/v14.7.0/bin/node

So I added the corresponding directory to my path.

How/where should the node package be installed? It would be done and owned by root, of course.

Comment: Do you actually have multiple human beings wanting to use node on the same computer? That's pretty uncommon these days since computers are so cheap everyone has one (or several).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you install Node.JS on CentOS?](https://serverfault.com/questions/299288/how-do-you-install-node-js-on-centos)

Comment: Michael: My goal is to run a server application based on node.js. More specifically, this one: https://github.com/potree/potree. The users are actually two developers.

Comment: Yes, Christopher, it seems that my question is answered there, in that 9 year old post. The installation takes over one hour, so I am not 100% sure. Keeping my finger crossed.

Answer (score 0):

You want to install NodeJS to `/usr/bin`. Installing an application to a user's home directory and giving others access to that directory is not considered best practice, and should only ever be done for very short-term requirements. You'd also need to grant the other users read access to that directory, which has the potential to cause issues.

Comment: I found more details here: https://serverfault.com/questions/299288/how-do-you-install-node-js-on-centos